# Expecting a password in the middle of script in RHEL

Tags: centos, linux-networking, shell-scripting, scp, rhel8

I want to copy files from another server it's expecting a password to copy... Where as sshpass is working in Ubuntu, but in RHEL is there a way to pass the password in the script.

Comment: can you please share the script that you are using ?

Comment: you can check this article for more info https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-automation-sshpass

Answer (score 2):

sshpass is available from [EPEL repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories). Technically not a part of CentOS, but easy to enable if you wish.

Passwords are insecure, consider any other method of ssh auth instead. sshpass's reason for existing is a hack to get around OpenSSH intentionally making this difficult.